# extending a retain property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a retain property, which is an NSArray of child View controllers. I want to modify the setter of this property so that when the view controllers are set I set a property on the view controller containing a reference to self.
In the same way when you add a view controller to a tab bar controller, the view controllers `tabBarController` property is set.

Should I be creating a custom setter (rather than the synthesized one) or should /i be using key value observing I think I've heard about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you could do it either way, my personal opinion would be to use a custom setter - if only because it would make it clearer for a third-party exactly what was doing what in the code. Using your own setter is probably more readable than setting up a key-value observer and having a method triggered upon a property change.

Also, from a computational perspective using KVO is more expensive than a custom setter. The impact in your application may be negligible, but it's worth considering.

Comment: What exactly is the code @synthesize is a shortcut for, the Apple docs give 3 different versions for retain, and I'm not sure which to use.

Comment: @synthesize automatically generates the getter/setter methods at compile time.